# Equivalent of ps -A | grep -c process in Windows?

Tags: windows, linux, process, grep, ps

I am looking for an equivalent/alternative of Linux's `ps -A | grep -c script.php` for Microsoft Windows?

Comment: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/summary.html - you _can_ run exactly that on Windows.

Comment: can I pipe it through the PHP ? i.e. system() ?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Simple commands:

```
tasklist | FIND "script.php"
```

Comment: piping `tasklist` into other programs to grep should be avoided, just like in Linux you should use `pgrep -l proc` instead of `ps -A | grep proc` because it's shorter, faster (because only 1 process is spawned) and more correct (because it avoids race condition)

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc You said what he shouldn't use, but not what he should use. Care to show that as well for completeness?

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc I did, but you hadn't referred to it before, so there was no link between your comment and his answer. Besides, his isn't the accepted answer.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar being accepted just mean that it helps the OP. It doesn't mean that it's the best way. As I said you shouldn't pipe tasklist output due to the above issues, the other answer fits the criteria and there's no reason mentioning it again in my comment

Answer (score 10):

An alternative solution to the accepted answer

```
tasklist /fi "Imagename eq script*"
```

In case you need this in a loop

```
for /l %x in (1, 0, 2) do (timeout /t 2 | tasklist /fi "Imagename eq script*")
```

Source:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491010.aspx

Comment: This answer is neater than the accepted one.  `/fi` also supports querying by `windowtitle`.  The Wildcard only seems to work as a suffix, but if more control is needed, it's still ultimately possible to pipe to `find` as above.
You can also use `/fo` to format as CSV, which would be useful for processing in Powershell.